# Changing the field value of unique and non-unique objects

Tags: java, algorithm, function, collections, stream

I have such a product class.

```
@Data
public class Product {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private String categoryName;
    private String frontName;
}
```

And I have a list of products - some product names are the same even though they have different category.I need to do the following for products that have the same names:
product.setFrontName(product.getName() + "," product.getCategoryName())

And for products with unique names, it's just to do: product.setFrontName(product.getName())

I tried various options with streams, but in the end I could not find a solution.

Could you share a more efficient solution to this task. Thank you.

Comment: What if you have a Product with a unique name in your DB and add another with the same name (but other category) should the formally unique one also change its name in the DB?

Comment: We need to see your code when you add a new Product because in this case you may need to change the FrontName of the new Product and potentially also of an old one.

Comment: Its a two step process. First you need to identify which are the unique names. Ones you have done this, you can perform the required operations

Comment: @XtremeBaumer There is a list of products class Product. If a sheet contains a product whose name occurs only once in the collection, it is unique. And for it I need to do product.setFrontName(product.getName).

Comment: If the list contains products whose name occurs more than once, then it is not unique and for such a product I need to do product.setFrontName (product.getName + "," product.getCategoryName)

Comment: Still a two step process. You need to identify the unique ones within your code, which is easiest done with counting occurrences of names. Ones you have a list of the unique ones, you can iterate all products and check if the name is in the unique list and depending on the result you perform the required action

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes, I understand that I need to do exactly that. But I'm having trouble with the implementation (

Answer (score 2):

please see the following code:

```
Set<String> items = new HashSet<>()
Set<String> duplicateProduct = 
    productList
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> !items.add(p.name))
            .map(Product::getName) // Set.add() returns false if the element was already in the set.
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    productList.forEach( p ->{
       if(duplicateProduct.contains(p.getName())){
           p.setFrontName(p.getName() + "," + p.getCategoryName());
       } else {
           p.setFrontName(p.getName());
       }
    });
```

Comment: This Answer could be improved with some explanation. Stack Overflow is meant to me more than a code snippet library.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can approach a solution.

My first idea is for example say that you have a List< Product> containing all the products, then you need to:

1. Iterate through all the products and save each product by name in a Map<String, List< Product>>. Products under the same name should be stored in the List< Product> value that has the name as key.
2. Iterate through all the entries of this map and check if the size of the list is greater than 1, it means the product has duplicate (or more) name with other products. Otherwise it's unique.